Sequential updating of tables in postgres
How to process layers in DWH. There was an idea to make triggers when updating the raw data layer, but it is difficult to maintain and a large load on the database is possible, I also thought to process further using airflow, but it turns out a lot of useless logic
Please tell me the current trends in the use of data layer processing methods in DWH
An ETL process has been created based on airflow to update the raw data layer in DWH, then the tables with raw data are cleaned and aggregated, and eventually the final storefronts are generated after that
